# How to send message to specific user by only userid in Azure signalr?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

Hi I am working in azure SignalR. I have made setup to send message to specif user by using combination of connectionid and userid and this works perfect for me.

```
public class UserConnectionManager : IUserConnectionManager
        private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> userConnectionMap = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        private static string userConnectionMapLocker = string.Empty;
        public void KeepUserConnection(string userId, string connectionId)
        {
            lock (userConnectionMapLocker)
            {
                if (!userConnectionMap.ContainsKey(userId))
                {
                    userConnectionMap[userId] = new List<string>();
                }
                userConnectionMap[userId].Add(connectionId);
            }
        }
```

For me this implementation works perfect. Now I have deployed my app in kubernetes with two pods so whats happening is list I used to store connectionids is static and kind of session behavior. So its not working with two pods.

```
[Route("Push")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Push(Failure Failure)
        {
          var connections = _userConnectionManager.GetUserConnections(Failure.UserId);
            if (connections != null && connections.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var connectionId in connections)
                {
                    await _notificationUserHubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("MyMessage", Failure);
                }
            }
      return ok();
}
```

So I do not want to make combination of connectioid and userid. I want to just push message to user by only userid. However I tried below approach

> await
> _notificationUserHubContext.Clients.User(Failure.UserId).SendAsync("MyMessage",
> mapDataResponseSuccess);

This piece of code is not pushing messages to specified userid. Can someone help me to send message to specific user by only UserId? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Along with your code snippet, that seems one user could have one more conversation as you used `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` to mapping the relationship between user and conversation. So I'm afraid that's impossible to only use user id to send message to specific conversation. Did I misunderstand in some place?

Comment: I am using combination of userid and connectionid and the current implementation is working. But what i am looking is now i dont want to have combination with connectiion id and just to user i want to send messages

Comment: My colleague told me [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/redis-backplane?view=aspnetcore-5.0) can help you, and also told me that azure signalr service is designed for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot tiny Wang, I will go through documentation